# Is there something like AppVerifier or Driver Verifier for Linux?

Tags: linux, testing

I am hoping that someone can point me toward Linux software similar to the Microsoft tools [Application Verifier](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb457063.aspx) and [Driver Verifier](http://www.microsoft.com/whdc/DevTools/tools/DrvVerifier.mspx). (They are stress testers for Windows applications and drivers, respectively.)

Do such things exist for Linux?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm not familiar with Application Verifier and Driver Verifier at all...

For applications, [Valgrind](http://valgrind.org/) is very useful as a tool to check for leaks, use-after-free, double free, buffer overflow, use of unitialized data, unsafe concurrent data access, and much more.

There also exist many [fuzzers](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fuzz_testing) ([zzuf](http://caca.zoy.org/wiki/zzuf), [fusil](http://fusil.hachoir.org/), etc.) which test a program's resiliance to invalid input.

GCC itself has `-fstackprotector`, which enables SSP (stack-smashing protector, aka ProPolice); `-fmudflap`, which detecs some other bad memory usage; and (in conjunction with `glibc`) `-D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=`*n*, which puts extra checking on various string and memory functions.

In the Linux kernel, there are many configuration switches under the "Kernel hacking" menu:

- `CONFIG_DEBUG_SLAB`, `CONFIG_DEBUG_PAGEALLOC`, etc., which ensure that memory is allocated, used, and freed sanely
- `CONFIG_DEBUG_OBJECTS`, which checks that objects are used and freed orderly
- [kmemcheck](http://git.kernel.org/?p=linux/kernel/git/vegard/kmemcheck.git), "Valgrind for the kernel"
- [`CONFIG_PROVE_LOCKING`](http://git.kernel.org/?p=linux/kernel/git/torvalds/linux-2.6.git;a=blob;f=Documentation/lockdep-design.txt;hb=HEAD), which analyzes for all possible deadlocks
- `CONFIG_DEBUG_PREEMPT`, `CONFIG_DEBUG_MUTEXES`, `CONFIG_DEBUG_SPINLOCK`, `CONFIG_DEBUG_SPINLOCK_SLEEP`, etc., which warn on improper use of locking
- [`CONFIG_FAULT_INJECTION` & co.](http://git.kernel.org/?p=linux/kernel/git/torvalds/linux-2.6.git;a=blob;f=Documentation/fault-injection/fault-injection.txt;hb=HEAD), which probabilistically cause failures of memory allocation and I/O